# Passing struct by value from an explicitly loaded dll built with a different compiler

Tags: c++, windows, dll

As far as I know it is safe to pass a struct across libraries, if the padding is compatible. So I wrote a test with a struct containing a single member, yet I still get a runtime error when reading the returned struct.

PluginInterface.h:

```
#ifndef PLUGIN_INTERFACE_H
#define PLUGIN_INTERFACE_H

typedef struct {
    const char *name;
} DataStruct;

class PluginInterface {
public:
    virtual DataStruct __cdecl getData() = 0;
};

#endif // PLUGIN_INTERFACE_H
```

Plugin.h:

```
#ifndef PLUGIN_H
#define PLUGIN_H

#include "PluginInterface.h"

class Plugin : public PluginInterface {
public:
    DataStruct __cdecl getData();
};

#endif // PLUGIN_H
```

Plugin.cpp:

```
#include "Plugin.h"

DataStruct Plugin::getData() {
    DataStruct data;
    data.name = "name of plugin";
    return data;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) PluginInterface* getInstance() {
    return new Plugin;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "PluginInterface.h"

typedef PluginInterface* (*PluginCreator) ();

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE handle = LoadLibrary("Plugin.dll");
    if (handle == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file!" << std::endl; return 0;
    }

    PluginCreator creator = (PluginCreator)GetProcAddress(handle, "getInstance");
    if (creator == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Unable to load file!" << std::endl; return 0;
    }

    PluginInterface* plugin = creator();
    if (plugin == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Unable to create plugin!" << std::endl; return 0;
    }

    DataStruct data = plugin->getData();
    std::cout << "so far so good" << std::endl;

    std::cout << data.name << std::endl; // Access violation

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the plugin with mingw, the executable with VS2012. I also tried to replace the const char* with an int, in which case I get a random integer.
I know passing a struct with a single element doesn't make much sense, but I still wonder what the problem is.

Comment: getInstance must be dectared as `__declspec(dllexport)` in dll, and `__declspec(dllimport)` in the client project. Try also to remove `__cdecl` from class methods, I don't see any reason to use it.

Comment: According to [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271769(v=vs.60).aspx) dllimport is not necessary, but even after adding it in the client project, nothing changed. I used the __cdecl, because otherwise I get a runtime error mentioning different calling convenctions.

Comment: If the libraries are compiled with different compilers, have you checked that they both have the same C++ ABI?

Comment: data._name or data.name? Is this the exact code you have the problem with?

Comment: As far as I know gcc and vs2012 don't have the same c++ abi, but that's exactly what I want. I'm passing pod structs, so I can compile plugins with different compilers.

Comment: The code is just slightly edited, the 'data._name' was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with passing the struct by value, as this would work if the function returning the struct was a non-member declared `extern "C"`. The problem is with the call to the virtual function `getData()`. In your example, the VS2012 compiler generates the code to call the virtual function via a pointer to an object, but the object was created by code generated by a different compiler. This fails because the C++ ABI differs between the two compilers - which means that the underlying implementation of virtual functions is different.

The call to `creator` succeeds because both compilers have the same underlying implemention of the C ABI. If you want to use C++ across library boundaries, you need to ensure that the libraries are compiled with the same C++ ABI version. Note that this can differ between different versions of the same compiler.

Comment: Note that the fact that there is no runtime error during the call to `getData` does not mean that the call to `getData` succeeded. In this case, the call to `getData()` either executes code or overwrites memory at a random address, while leaving `data` uninitialised.

Comment: Ok I understand the problem now. But what about existing libraries with plugin architectures? Qt plugins for example implement the member function `keys` which returns a QStringList: [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyleplugin.html#keys). Does that mean that a Qt plugin compiled with some exotic compiler wouldn't work?

Comment: @ButeoAter Yes, Qt plugins can only be loaded if they were built with a compatible C++ ABI. This is mentioned in the documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-plugins.html#the-build-key